# Encrypt fields and get searchon them with Sharepoint

Tags: search, sharepoint, encryption

We need to encrypt high sensitive information in Sharepoint. Even db/server admin should not be able to see encrypted fields. In the meantime we need search function on encrypted values with reasonable response time.

TDE seems not to be helpful against admins.
We have about 40 columns so cell encryption also seems to be helpless as it can result in very slow search.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: If the server can read the key, the admin can also.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: If your attacker has admin access, you cannot defend against him.

Comment: Maybe storing data in external database/data storage, and accessing to it via BCS service with custom connector would be a better option? It could be even possible, to use standard SharePoint Search to retrieve data, but - with this you would anyway have to be careful, since CrawlAccount may still have access to this confidential data.